# PHP sum of all variable in while loop while echoing the individual result

Tags: php

Hi i want to display all overall total of $sum2 while displaying the $sum2 this is the example:

```
<?php $sum2+=$row_acc_rec_pay['counter'] * $row_acc_rec_pay['amount'];
  } while ($row_acc_rec_pay = mysql_fetch_assoc($acc_rec_pay)); ?>

<td>Total:<?php echo $sum2; echo $sum2=0;?></td>

<td> Overall Total=<td>
```

So the output will be:

```
test    amount  Sec Course
1   100 3A  BSCS     
3   300 4A  BSCS     
1   100 4B  BSCS     
1   100 3A  BSIS     
3   300 4A  BSIS     
1   100 2A  BSIT     
Total:1000

T-Shirt Fee amount  Sec Course
1   250 3A  BSCS     
3   750 4A  BSCS     
1   250 4B  BSCS     
1   250 3A  BSIS     
3   750 4A  BSIS     
1   250 2A  BSIT     
10  2500    4A  BSIT     
Total:5000


Membership Fee  amount  Sec Course
1   25  3A  BSCS     
3   75  4A  BSCS     
1   25  4B  BSCS     
1   25  3A  BSIS     
10  250 4A  BSIS     
1   25  2A  BSIT     
10  250 4A  BSIT     
Total:675

Overall Total:
```

i want to add all $sum2 and display it as $overall its really irritating thanks!

Comment: `<td>Total:<?php echo $sum2; $totalSum += $sum2; $sum2 = 0;?></td> <td> Overall Total=<?= $totalSum ?><td>` And declare `$totalSum = 0;` before you start your while loop, does that do the trick for you?

Comment: it totally works! Thanks man!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just change this line:

```
<td>Total:<?php echo $sum2; echo $sum2=0;?></td>
//...
<td> Overall Total=<td>
```

to:

```
<td>Total:<?php echo $sum2; $totalSum += $sum2; $sum2 = 0;?>
//...
</td> <td> Overall Total=<?= $totalSum ?><td>
```

And declare `$totalSum = 0;` before you start your while loop

Answer (score 0):

You should consider doing some of the math in sql beforehand. 
I suppose you want something like that:

```
<?php $sum2=0; $overall=0;?>

<table>
   <thead>
      <tr>
         <th>test</th>
         ...
         <th>Course</th>
      </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
   <?php while($row_acc_rec_pay = mysql_fetch_assoc($acc_rec_pay)): ?>
      <tr>
         <td>...
      </tr>
      <?php $sum2 += $row_acc_rec_pay['counter'] * $row_acc_rec_pay['amount']; ?>
   <?php endwhile; ?>
   </tbody>
</table>
Total: <?= $sum2 ?>;
<?php $overall += $sum2; $sum2 = 0; ?>

[REPEAT FOR THE OTHER TWO TABLES]

Overall Total: <?= $overall; ?>
```